# pgfplots wont graph my function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, draw

I would like to plot a graph like [image]

But my code simply does not work

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=18cm,
 axis lines=middle,
 xmin=0,xmax=1.02,
 ymin=0.86,ymax=1.02,,
 xlabel=\Large $c$,ylabel=\Large $F_g$,
 xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
 ytick={0.88,0.94,0.98,1},
        ]
\addplot[blue,samples=800,domain=0:1,smooth] {0.25*((sqrt{(1+(\x))*(1+ (sqrt{\x}))}) + (sqrt{((1+(\x))*(1+(sqrt{\x})))}))^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The function is given by [image]

Can someone help me with this, I think that it is a minor issue with ploting things like (1+\x) because these do not seam to work. Therefore something like (f(\x) + g(\x))^2 will never work. Is there a typo or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: i) You are using pgfplots, not pure TikZ - I changed your title. ii) It is better, if you post  your examples runable, so helpers can test an try out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've entered the wrong function (`+` in both terms, one should have `-`), and you should have `sqrt(x)` not `sqrt{x}`, for that matter.

Something else is wrong as well, but I just rewrote from scratch:

```
\addplot[blue,samples=80,domain=0:1,smooth] {0.25*(sqrt((1-x)*(1-sqrt(x))) + sqrt((1+x)*(1+sqrt(x))))^2};
```

Complete code, with some modifications of axis limits and ticklabels:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 width=18cm,
 axis lines=middle,
 xmin=0,xmax=1.02,
 ymin=0.98,ymax=1.01,
 xlabel=\Large $c$,ylabel=\Large $F_g$,
 xtick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
 ytick={0.98,0.985,...,1.01},
 yticklabel style={
   /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
   /pgf/number format/precision=3,
   }
        ]
\addplot[blue,samples=80,domain=0:1,smooth] {0.25*(sqrt((1-x)*(1-sqrt(x))) + sqrt((1+x)*(1+sqrt(x))))^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh gosh I tilted hard, sorry I'm coding this project in LaTeX15 hours straight

Comment: The other problem this answer fixes is using `x` instead of `\x`.

Comment: @Teepeemm Well that's not really a problem. I did change it, mostly because I prefer `x`, but as far as `pgfplots` is concerned, it's the same in this case (page 54 in the manual).